# LLVM: Efficient way to cast struct

Tags: generics, llvm

I have a function that represents shared generic code that returns a generic struct declared

```
%"GenStruct<System.__Canon>" = type <{ i32, i32 }>
```

The calling code wants the concrete type (as it will later pass that to another non-shared function)

```
%"GenStruct<string>" = type <{ i32, i32 }>
```

(This is a .Net => LLVM compiler BTW).  `System.__Canon` represents the generic type and `string` is the concrete type.
The structs are identical, if they weren't this would not be using shared code, but its not possible to cast structs in LLVM with a bitcast, so I have:

```
  %3 = call %"GenStruct<System.__Canon>" @"HelloWasm_Program_GenStructWithImplicitOp_1<System___Canon>__op_Implicit"(i8* %1, i8* %CastPtr)
  %memStruct = alloca %"GenStruct<System.__Canon>"
  store %"GenStruct<System.__Canon>" %3, %"GenStruct<System.__Canon>"* %memStruct,
  %castPtr = bitcast %"GenStruct<System.__Canon>"* %memStruct to %"GenStruct<string>"*
  %Loadop_Implicit_return = load %"GenStruct<string>", %"GenStruct<string>"* %castPtr
```

where `HelloWasm_Program_GenStructWithImplicitOp_1<System___Canon>__op_Implicit` is the shared generic method which returns the generic type.
I've done an `alloca` to get a pointer and cast that.  This works but would seem to be inefficient in that it does an alloc and store/load.  Is there a way round this, or should I not worry as in the final compilation (in this case to Wasm) this will be optimized away?

Comment: This isn't an answer, merely a comment. You could implement the cast by a generated sequence of extractvalue, cast and insertvalue instructions, which *ought* to lead to excellent code. In case of your example, there would be no casts, of course, but more generally casting primitive fields in the struct might be necessary in order to match .Net's promotion rules using LLVM.

Comment: @arnt that certainly produces a smaller Wast, thanks.